# List of Kleisli to Kleisli of list

Tags: scala, scala-cats, kleisli

I was wondering if there is a way to turn `List[Kleisli[Option, Int, Int]]` to `Kleisli[Option, Int, List[Int]]`.

In particular I have the list of kleisli formed like this:

```
def k(a: String) = Kleisli[Option, Int, Int](m => Some(a.length * m))
val kList = List("hi", "hello").map(k)
```

What I do is the following

```
Kleisli[Option, Int, List[Int]](m => kList.map(_.run(m)).sequence)
```

which is very messy, not expressive and requires a lot of manual work.

Is there a better way?

Comment: apart from the great answers below, I'd like to stress the fact that `sequence o map` (i.e. doing `map` and then doing `sequence`) is equivalent to `traverse` in the general case. This may help you refactor several other parts of your codebase ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use `traverse` which does just that. If you're using `cats` <= 0.9.0 you can use the following code:

```
import cats.data._
import cats.instances.list._
import cats.instances.option._
import cats.syntax.traverse._

// ...
def k(a: String) = Kleisli[Option, Int, Int](m => Some(a.length * m))
val result: Kleisli[Option, Int, List[Int] = List("hi", "hello").traverseU(k)
```

If you're using Scala 2.11.9+, by adding `scalacOptions += "-Ypartial-unification"` to your `build.sbt` file, you can just use `traverse` in place of `traverseU`. Also, starting from version 1.0.0, `traverseU` and `sequenceU` will no longer exist.

Note that, if you're using Scala < 2.11.9 but >= 2.10.6 you can still enable partial unification by adding [this plugin](https://github.com/fiadliel/sbt-partial-unification#sbt-partial-unification) to your build.

Comment: I would add (as Luka said in his answer) that in cats version 1.0.0 you will need the `-Y-partial-unification` flag to make `traverse` compile ;)

Comment: Yeah, I hadn't written it because it's clearly stated in cats's github page but you're right, adding it will do no harm. ;)

Comment: Why do we need the flag tho? Why is this not default?

Comment: I guess because, even if it fixed a long-lasted [SI-2712](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2712) problem, it's something that was recently fixed so, even if we all are confident it doesn't break anything else, for cautiousness it's enabled through an explicit flag. Here you can find the [PR](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5102) against the scalac.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest you can do is to have `partial-unification` enabled and using `traverse`:

```
import cats.implicits._

List("hi", "hello").traverse(k)
```

This is the same as running `sequence` on your `kList`, as `traverse` is equivalent to `map` and then `sequence`.

The easiest way to enable `partial-unification`, is to add the `sbt-partial-unification` [plugin](https://github.com/fiadliel/sbt-partial-unification).

If you're on Scala 2.11.9 or newer, you can also simply add the compiler flag:

```
scalacOptions += "-Ypartial-unification"
```

We from the `cats` team strongly encourage you to have this flag on at all times when using cats, as it makes everything just a lot easier.

Comment: Are you sure enabling partial-unification would work also with the 0.9.0 version of cats? I think they removed the Unapply enabled methods, e.g. sequenceU, traverseU in the 1.0.0-MF. In this case your code wouldn't work with version 0.9.0.

Comment: I see, traverseU and sequenceU were removed in 1.0.0-MF but, on the other hand, partial-unification will make traverse work even with previous version of cats.

Answer (score 2):

Using `TraverseOps.sequence` we can transform `List[A[B]]` to `A[List[B]]`, where

```
A = ({type λ[α] = Kleisli[Option, Int, α]})#λ
B = Int
```

So the answer is:

```
def transform(x: List[Kleisli[Option, Int, Int]]) =
  x.sequence[({type λ[α] = Kleisli[Option, Int, α]})#λ, Int]
```

Following code is complete solution:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
import scalaz.Kleisli._

def transform(x: List[Kleisli[Option, Int, Int]]) = x.sequence[({type λ[α] = Kleisli[Option, Int, α]})#λ, Int]

def k(a: String) = Kleisli[Option, Int, Int](m => Some(a.length * m))
val kList = List("hi", "hello").map(k)
val res = transform(kList)
res.run(10)
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/2uZvWWb1ScOHNA55QOcWQA